# Give example of convergent and divergent sequences of positive numbers such that lim $x_n^{\frac1n}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

So basically I have to give examples where the root test doesn't work, right?

For the convergent sequence, I'm taking $x_n=(1,1,1,\cdots)$, then lim $x_n^{\frac1n}=1$

Is there any non-constant sequence that I can use instead?

For the divergent sequence, I'm taking $x_n=(n)$, then lim  $x_n^{\frac1n}$=lim $n^{\frac1n}=1$

Are these suitable examples?

Comment: The root test applies to series, not sequences.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski the divergent sequence $x_n$ doesn't need to have a limit. lim $x_n^{\frac1n}$ needs to exist. Thanks for correcting me about the root test. :)

Comment: yes, I misread the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, in these cases root test doesn't work.
2. Your example with constant sequence is the simpliest, but you can also take for instance $\displaystyle 1+\frac{1}{n}$, then:

$$1 \leq (1+\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq 2^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
 $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$

3. Yes, your examples are suitable.